# Xcode close the project when i tried to compile it

Tags: c, xcode, macos, unix, ide

I have this problems with Xcode

when i try to compile a program the Xcode just close (randomly) the project where i'am working, this happen with any type of code, like "printf("%d",1+1) or any other more complex code. And don't happen every time, just some times.

And that it's, i don't know why this start to happen. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

I'm working with Command Line Tool, and the language is C.

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently upgrade to Yosemite? One of the reasons might be the upgrade.

Un-install and re-install Xcode and try.

For other internal problems you will need to send the code or a log of the error report.

Comment: yes, i upgraded to Yosemite. I already did the un/re-install, and still happens...